# Can't find a div-name with Selenium in Pyhon, NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, fetch

I'm a beginner to python, so please be caution with me.

I'm trying to find this on a Website:

```
<div class="price">$ 1.67<span class="discount">-19.71%</span></div>
```

I'm using Selenium like this:

```
#chromedriver
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
ser = Service(executable_path='C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'

def Function():
    count = 0
    global driver

    with webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options) as driver:
        driver.get('https://cs.deals/market/csgo/Container/?name=phoeni&sort=price')
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        wait.until(page_has_loaded)

        container = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'price')
        print(container)

    return
```

I also tried "By.CLASS_NAME" and "By.XPATH"

Exeption-Message:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="price"]"}

Where is my mistake?

I tried to get the first (the lowest) price, but instead I got this exeption.

Comment: "price" is not an id, it's a class. it should be ```driver.find_element(By.ID, 'price')```. Did you try that and it didn't work?

Comment: Ah also just noticed in the error message, it says ```"method":"css selector,"selector":"[id="price"]""``` meaning its trying to find the element by searching for css selector. The css selector for this would be ```div.price```
I'm not sure why it is searching via CSS selector, maybe someone else knows why.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the price information ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://cs.deals/market/csgo/Container/?name=phoeni&sort=price')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#cookie-consent-accept"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.main-content-margin div.price"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://cs.deals/market/csgo/Container/?name=phoeni&sort=price')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='cookie-consent-accept']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='main-content-margin']//div[@class='price']"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  $ 1.67-19.71%
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: The cookies... Thats it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Hello undetected Selenium.

Comment: As already said, it works. But now I have the problem that this code performs very inefficient. It takes around 5-10 seconds for each value to get from the homepage.
Do you have an idea, how to improve this?

Comment: @Do0dl3r I have to look in your entire code to comment further.